# Server unable to send mails. All mails waiting in queue

Tags: linux, postfix

The mails sent are waiting in queue with the error below:

```
`(Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=srvr1.com.my type=MX: Host not found, try again)`
```

However, I have defined the host entry for that domain in `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

Your entry in the hosts-file helpless in this case.
You must use the DNS-server(BIND, for example) and create MX-entry there.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with the hosts file? Because we do not have any dns in the environment

Comment: No. The hosts file only resolves names to IPs. It doesn't support any type of DNS records.

Answer (score 0):

For sending/relay emails for another email server lacking DNS, as the error message is complaining, you have got to define a `postfix` smarthost.

As such, configure `relayhost` in `postfix.cf` with the address of the destination email server, as in:

```
relayhost = my_email.server.fqdn
```

You can use also an IP address instead of a name.

Lastly, restart `postfix`  as in:

```
service postfix restart
```